# Can you display a framed source code with file name in reStructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

I'm looking for a way to display source code in a box showing the file name.

For example, like this:

[image]

Any way to do this with reStructuredText?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-made directive for this in standard rST.
You may use and style a suitable block-level element, e.g.,

```
.. admonition:: myfile.py

   .. include:: myfile.py
      :code: python
```